# Prove the integral equals the factorial function for all natural numbers, and converges for all real

Tags: calculus

For $x > −1$, let $f(x)=\int_0^∞t^xe^{−t} dt$. Show that $f(n)=n!$ for all $n∈\Bbb N∪\{0\}$, and show that
$f(x)$ converges for all $x>−1,x∈\Bbb R$.

My intuition tells me that this question can be solved by somehow applying $e^x = \sum_0^∞ \frac{x^n}{n!}$, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it (or perhaps this isn't how you solve it).

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Try to prove it satisfies the factorial recurrence relation, namely $f(n) = n \cdot f(n-1)$ by induction, with the initial condition $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: The integrals of $t^x(-t)^n$ diverge. Taylor will not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show it is the factorial for $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ using integration by parts:

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}\,dt&=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}[-t^ne^{-t}]_0^Mn\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=n\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=nf(n-1)
\end{align}
Proceeding inductively,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}\,dt&=n!\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,dt\\
&=n!
\end{align}

To see that $f(x)$ converges for $x>-1$ note that $e^{-t}$ will decay faster at infinity than any polynomial.